# Session handling between 2 apps

Tags: angularjs, session, tomcat, frontend, backend

I have two apps. Appp1 is front end developed in angular  running on nodejs and app2 is back end rest services running on tomcat. How exactly session will be shared between these two apps? My login.html and controller is in app1. I am making rest call to app2 to authenticate user. How session will be shared from browser to app1 to app2?

Thanks 
Ravi

Answer (score -1):

One way could be HTML5 localStorage.

Comment: can you give more details? Example user will hit login.html that is running on app1 on server 1. app1 will make ajax call to authentication service running on app2. App2 will create session that is on server2. This session_id will passed from app2 to app1 and browser will store it on localstorage. But in next call say home.html...how session_id stored on brower will be passed to app2. As session is specific to server. actual session was created on app2/server2. Now app2 will treat it as new session...Correct me where i am going wrong.? How exactly two servers will exchange session...